# How can I open Evince as root?

Tags: evince

How can I open Evince as root?

I have tried 'sudo evince', 'sudo document-viewer', etc.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens wjen you run `sudo evince`? What error do you get? Have you tried with the full path? `sudo $(type -p evince)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why would you try to open a PDF reader as root? Please think about whether this is really necessary. Remember that PDF and PostScript files can contain viruses, which exploit bugs in the reader software (although they are most often targeted at Adobe's Acrobat Reader, as it is the most far spread PDF viewer).

Please do not run any GUI application with `sudo`. It could mess up your permissions in your home directory. Use `gksudo` instead. You may have to install the package `gksu` before. Then you can open Evince (if you really decide that it is necessary) with

```
gksudo evince
```

Comment: The reason is that I keep my files on an encrypted sd card, and I cannot access .pdf files with Thunar, even as root (Xubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Most of the .pdf files on my system are stuff I have printed from Firefox, articles, shopping, etc.

Comment: While we are on this subject, is there a danger in running Firefox as root? I sometimes do this because I can also access files on the sd card...

Comment: And what encryption does require root read access after mounting the device?

Comment: I installed gksudo. When I try to open a .pdf via gksudo, I get this: user@user-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo su
[sudo] password for user: 
root@user-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/user# gksudo
No protocol specified

** (evince:2770): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: 
root@user-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/user#

Comment: Encryption is LUKS, formatted by gnome-disk-utility. It seems to be only .pdf files that I cannot access...

Comment: You are to run `gksudo evince` from your own account, not from a root shell.

Comment: Now I get: user@user-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$ gksudo

** (evince:2816): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display: 
user@user-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Try `gksudo -k evince`. Also compare `env` to `gksudo env`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24458/discussion-between-rcline7-and-the-seppi).

Comment: @RCline7 "is there a danger in running Firefox as root? " Oh definately yes